# Local variable reference before assignment - Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue in calculating a field in Model. Basically what I need to do is to calculate, based on the user HTML input, a certain date and a certain price.
The functions are giving me problem are the functions inside the models.py file.
The code is as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

# Create your models here.
RAMO_POLIZZA = (
    ('ITAS DANNI', 'ITAS DANNI'),
    ('ITAS ELEMENTARI', 'ITAS ELEMENTARI'),
    ('SARA DANNI', 'SARA DANNI'),
    ('SARA ELEMENTARI', 'SARA ELEMENTARI'),
)

FRAZIONAMENTO = (
    ('Annuale', 'Annuale'),
    ('Semestrale', 'Semestrale'),
    ('Quadrimestrale', 'Quadrimestrale'),
    ('Mensile', 'Mensile'),
)


class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cognome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    creata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cliente'
        ordering = ['cognome', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome + ' ' + self.cognome


class RamoPolizza(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RAMO_POLIZZA)
    creata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ramo Polizza'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Frazionamento(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FRAZIONAMENTO)
    creata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Frazionamento'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Polizza(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numero_polizza = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    data_decorrenza = models.DateField()
    data_scadenza = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ramo_polizza = models.ForeignKey(RamoPolizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    polizza_nuova = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    frazionamento = models.ForeignKey(Frazionamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    premio = models.FloatField()
    provvigione = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    creata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    aggiornata = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Polizza'
        ordering = ['data_scadenza']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ramo_polizza + ' ' + self.frazionamento

    @property
    def get_provvigione(self):
        if self.ramo_polizza == 'ITAS DANNI' and self.polizza_nuova == True:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 9)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'ITAS DANNI' and self.polizza_nuova == False:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 7)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'ITAS ELEMENTARI' and self.polizza_nuova == True:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 17)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'ITAS ELEMENTARI' and self.polizza_nuova == False:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 13)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'SARA DANNI' and self.polizza_nuova == True:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 7)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'SARA DANNI' and self.polizza_nuova == False:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 5)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'SARA ELEMENTARI' and self.polizza_nuova == True:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 17)/100
        elif self.ramo_polizza == 'SARA ELEMENTARI' and self.polizza_nuova == False:
            provvigione = (self.premio * 13)/100

        return provvigione

    @property
    def get_data_scadenza(self):
        data_decorrenza = dt.strptime(self.data_decorrenza, '%Y-%m-%d')
        if self.frazionamento == 'Annuale':
            data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=365)
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Semestrale':
            data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=180)
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Quadrimestrale':
            data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=120)
        elif self.frazionamento == 'Mensile':
            data_scadenza = data_decorrenza + timedelta(days=30)

        return data_scadenza

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.provvigione = self.get_provvigione
        self.data_scadenza = self.get_data_scadenza
        super(Polizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def nuova_polizza(request):
    clienti = Cliente.objects.all()
    frazionamenti = Frazionamento.objects.all()
    rami_polizza = RamoPolizza.objects.all()
    context = {
        'clienti': clienti,
        'frazionamenti': frazionamenti,
        'rami_polizza': rami_polizza,

    }
    return render(request, 'anagrafica/nuova_polizza.html', context)


def salva_nuova_polizza(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cliente = request.POST.get('cliente')
        numero_polizza = request.POST.get('numero_polizza')
        data_decorrenza = request.POST.get('data_decorrenza')
        ramo_polizza = request.POST.get('ramo_polizza')
        frazionamento = request.POST.get('frazionamento')
        premio = int(request.POST.get('premio'))

        polizza = Polizza(cliente_id=cliente, numero_polizza=numero_polizza, data_decorrenza=data_decorrenza,
                          ramo_polizza_id=ramo_polizza, frazionamento_id=frazionamento, premio=premio)
        polizza.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('anagrafica:lista_clienti'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Metodo non Consentito')
```

The error I'm having is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Django 3.2/pennygest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Django 3.2/pennygest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Django 3.2/pennygest/pennygest/anagrafica/views.py", line 68, in salva_nuova_polizza
    polizza.save()
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Django 3.2/pennygest/pennygest/anagrafica/models.py", line 116, in save
    self.provvigione = self.get_provvigione
  File "/Users/Giorgio 1/Documents/Django 3.2/pennygest/pennygest/anagrafica/models.py", line 99, in get_provvigione
    return provvigione
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'provvigione' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestion? I tried to understand how it can happen everywhere but I didn't find the solution yet.
It looks like it's some kind of error in property inside the model functions, but I am not sure.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The variable is only assigned if atleast one of the conditions are met in the `if elif` block, it just means none of the conditions were met and the variable remained unassigned. Try assigning a default value to the variable at the start of the function or under an `else` statement.

Comment: Thanks man!!! That solved the issue!!!